# Popup won't show up on first click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to show a popup when a user clicks on the icon. The popup should only show up when the url doesn't contain "chrome://" or "about:". That works well. But on a normal page, the popup only appears when I click on the icon for the second time. Nothing happens on the first click. Here's the code for from background.html

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (!tab.url.indexOf('chrome://') ||!tab.url.indexOf('about:')) {
        alert('For security reasons, this page cannot shared.');
        return;
    }
    else {
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({tabId:tab.id,popup:"html/popup.html"});
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try checking if the `tab.status` is `"complete"`? It may be that it won't be able to show until the page was properly loaded.

Comment: Does't matter whether the page is completely loaded or not, the popup only appears when clicked 2nd time.

Comment: @vivek did you figure this out?? Got the same requirement

Comment: @williamsowen I don't remember whether I was able to fix this or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After correctly replicating your problem, I found what's going on: **the reason why no popup is being show in the first click is because it doesn't have one to show.**

Think about it. You are setting up the popup *AFTER* you click on the browser icon. What's supposed to show? It doesn't know, but the event was already triggered, so the default mechanism doesn't know what to show. Inside your event handler, which is just a javascript mechanism not built in inside the browser, you then set it up, but it's already to late. However, a second time (and a third, forth, and so on) will actually show up a popup because now it knows which popup to show.

Solutions? The obvious one is to put the popup as part of your manifest.json, as everyone else:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
  "default_title": "browser action demo",
  "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
},
```

Of course doing this means that the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` won't be fired, but to be fair, you should give the users a landing popup to start with. If you want to chance the popup afterwards, then provide an interface that does that (a button that on click sends a message to the backgroundPage to change the popup).

Other option could be to have a handler `beforeShow` popup, but I wouldn't give my hopes up, as I haven't found anything like that in the API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing two mutually exclusive events to one functionality.

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is to be used when there is no popup used.

The following script is executed only once with your background.html

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log("Is fired..");
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "popup.html"
    });

});
```

If you want to change popup page on some arbitrary logic(Ex some url or content), put it in background page for every tab Id. BTW What is the business logic you are looking for?